# Search for SKOS prefLabel in Visual Graph

Tags: graphdb, skos

Is there a way to search for SKOS concepts by prefLabel (Visual graph)? Also, have prefLabels displayed in results?

Answer (score 0):

In all version before GraphDB 8.3, the only way to change the returned results is to edit the SPARQL query packaged as a resource file in a JAR file.

1. Make a copy of the distribution
2. Locate the JAR file in the distribution lib/workbench/WEB-INF/lib/graphdb-framework-graph-explore-.jar
3. Find the resource file ./graph-explore-queries/describeResource.sparql
4. Modify the query and replace `rdfs:label` with another predicate:

   ```
   PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
   PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
   PREFIX sesame: <http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#>
   PREFIX rank: <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/RDFRank#>

   SELECT ?type ?label ?rank ?langPriority {{from}} {
       {
           BIND ({{nodeiri}} as ?iri)
          {
              ?iri sesame:directType ?type.
          }
          UNION {
               ?iri rdfs:label ?label.
               BIND(LANG(?label) AS ?langLabel)
               BIND( {{langMatches}} AS ?langPriority)
           }
           UNION {
               ?iri rank:hasRDFRank ?rank
           }
       }
   } 
   ORDER BY ?type ?langPriority
   ```

   5. Repackage the JAR file and test the results.